# OpenXML WorksheetParts in reverse?

Tags: c#, openxml

I have the following code

```
        SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(name, true);
        foreach (WorksheetPart wsP in doc.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts)
        {
            SheetData sData = wsP.Worksheet.Descendants<SheetData>().First();
            var cells = sData.Descendants<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference.Value == "A1");
            if (cells.Count<Cell>() == 1)
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(cells.First().CellValue.Text);
                SharedStringItem str = doc.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>().ElementAt(index);
            }

        }
        Sheet sheet = doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.FirstChild as Sheet;
        doc.Close();
```

So far, I'm exploring OpenXML and just seeing how things work. I've come upon what seems to be an odd behavior. The file I am opening contains three sheets:

- "Instructions", who's A1 cell is "fck ="
- "Geometry", who's A1 cell is "PullDate"
- "Stresses", who's A1 cell is "Section"

If I tinker with the latter part of the code (`Sheet`) to go to different sheets (by appending a `.NextSibling` at the end), that is precisely the order of sheet titles I get (by using the debugger).

However, the `foreach WorksheetPart` section on top goes backwards, returning me the A1 cells as "Section" and then "PullDate" and then "fck =".

Is this the expected behavior or am I doing something foolishly wrong and not noticing?

Comment: I tested with your code on OpenXml 2.5 and I'm not seeing the backwards behavior you're describing. What version are you on?